# From a deck of 52 cards, the face cards and four 10's are removed. From these 16 cards four are choosen.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> From a deck of 52 cards, the face cards and four 10's are removed. From these 16 cards four are chosen. How many possible combinations are possible that have at least 2 red cards?

My solution I'm not sure how to enter the equation in to the calculator I believe my reasoning is correct but please do correct me if I'am wrong. "Calculator Ti-84"

At least 2 red cars:

=2 red 4c2x10c2=

=3 red 4C3x10c1=

=4 red: 4c4x10c0

A. 154

B. 518

C. 1302

D. 784

Comment: Uh, what happened to all the other cards?  If we only remove the face cards and $10$s we should have $4\times 9=36$ cards.

Comment: @Alexander I think the user intended: if we remove all cards other than  face cards and 10s, we'll have $16$ cards to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $16$ "removed cards" will contain $8$ red cards and $8$ black cards.

There are three possibilities to consider: the arrangements of four cards that we want to count will include the possible outcomes

- $2$ are red, $2$ are blue,
- $3$ red, $1$ blue,
- $4$ red

Summing gives us

$$\binom 82 \cdot \binom 82 + \binom 83\cdot \binom 81 + \binom 84 = \left(\frac{8!}{6!2!}\right)^2 + \frac{8!}{5!3!}\cdot 8 + \frac{8!}{4!4!}= 1302$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a pool of $8$ red cards and $8$ black ones.  All your selections involve only $14$ cards.  Otherwise your approach is fine.  Some text explanation for your expressions would make it *much* easier to understand-we don't all speak TI-84.  Better to format it with $\LaTeX$.   There are some hints [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)